# What are the downsides of an alternative Routing method that uses sub-controllers?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, routes, controller

I am writing a PHP CMS and I'm having some doubts about implementing the routing
the system that loads the page controller and "handles" it

I've seen many others implement the route like this:

```
//these values are actually retrieved from a file
return [
    ['GET', '/', ['Controllers\Homepage', 'show']],
    ['GET', '/user/recover/{token}', ['Controllers\User\Recover', 'recover']],
    ['GET', '/recover/{token}', ['Controllers\User\Recover', 'recover']],
    ['POST', '/user/login', ['Controllers\User\Login', 'login']],
    ['POST', '/login', ['Controllers\User\Login', 'login']],
    ['POST', '/user/register', ['Controllers\User\Register', 'register']],
    ['GET', '/foo/bar', ['Controllers\Idk', 'show']],
];
```

But I don't really like it, here is why:
If I call `example.com/user/recover/{token}` and `example.com/recover/{token}` the `Recover` controller needs to differentiate the two urls when handling a request, since `{token}` is in different positions and also there is the extra step for loading the routes **within** the controllers.
Also I prefer the a specific root is related to its own controller.

So I came up with this idea:
The application checks only the **first** parameter in the url (`https://example.com/firstparameter/secondparameter/third/etc`)
and loads from the database the controller name associated with the first parameter.

```
# don't worry, this is actually optimized with db normalization
+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------+
|       id       |        title        |  controller_name  | active |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------+
| firstparameter | just the page title | mycontroller      | (true) |
| user           | user page           | usercontroller    | (true) |
| recover        | recover             | recovercontroller | (true) |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Since the majority of the pages has its own title, description, etc. and all pages have a `controller_name` this database call almost always needs to made, independently by the routing method.
Therefore I don't see the need of using a file storing the routes when everything can be "togheter".

So if I call `example.com/user/recover/{token}`
Then the application loads `usercontroller` (constructs it with its dependencies) and then calls `usercontroller->init()`.
(note: Here I am not using different/dynamic method names by choice of simplicity because those can just be handled by each page's controller. Anyway that could be easily implemented later)

The `init()` function in this controller handles its whole page root `/user/*` and loads accordingly its sub-pages/children if there are any

```
function init(){
    if( secondparameter is user )
        /*  the second parameter becomes the first, so the 
        *   recovercontroller doens't need to do magic to get the url token
        *   for the recovercontroller the request will be almost the same 
        *   as calling example.com/recover/{token}
        */
        currenturl = arrayshift(currenturl)
        recover = new recovercontroller()
        recovercontroller->init()
        return
```

This seems complicated but it's actually more logic and simpler than the "traditional" routing method. Maybe someone has actually done this before.
What downsides does this method have compared to the traditional one?
More or less they do the same job.

Comment: if there is any doubt, critic or something, please comment!